# Avoiding accouting of empty line or space in default dict

Tags: python, defaultdict

I am using the default dict and split for reading a content from a text file.

Consider the text file is having following content.

```
cbdf25542c194a069464f69efff4859a 1.7.6.1
cbdf25542c194a069464f69efff4859a 1.6.7.1
cbdf25542c194a069464f69efff4859a 1.3.6.5
```

Now consider that it is having empty line in between, So it is returning an error instead of parsing it correctly.

How to get rid of the same.

It must be working fine even it have empty line in it.

Consider the code for the same below.

```
def _ip_fetch(current_tenant_id):

        results = defaultdict(list)
        with open(flat_text_file_location, 'r') as f:
                for row in f.readlines():
                        tenant_id, ip = row.split()
                        results[tenant_id].append(ip)
        ips = results.get(current_tenant_id, None)
        return ips
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a check to make sure the row has actual non-whitespace characters:

```
            for row in f.readlines():
                if row.strip():
                    tenant_id, ip = row.split()
                    results[tenant_id].append(ip)
```

Zero length strings evaluate to False in a boolean context, and all other strings evaluate to True, so this should be sufficient to detect empty lines.